# Программирование для платформы Windows CE 6.0 в IDE Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Добрый день!

Возникла необходимость написать приложение для платформы Windows CE 6.0.
Опыт разработки имеется на языке C# и C/C++. В основном пользовался Visual Studio.

Есть ли возможность использовать данную IDE для этой платформы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows CE 6.0 довольно устаревшая платформа. Согласно разным источникам, в современных версиях VS под неё официально [нельзя писать](https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/windowsce/relation-between-visual-studio-and-windows-ce-versions-2/), если вас устроит, [можно взять VS 2005](https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/windowsce/relation-between-visual-studio-and-windows-ce-versions/).

[Есть обходные пути для VS 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205155928/http://geekswithblogs.net/WernerWillemsens/archive/2013/09/13/building-windows-ce-6-or-7-smart-device-application-with.aspx)

Comment: Особых пристрастий к версии VS нет. На VS 2005 встает без танцев с бубном?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, [видео для VS 2008](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8umaGV-_Q0). В целом, как повезёт. На старых версиях Windows (XP, Vista) проблем не было. Как поведёт себя 10-ка - не знаю.